# How to use Entity Framework 6 Code First in Class Library Project with MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, class-library

I have a Class Library Project(.Net Framework) and Asp.Net MVC 5 project in same solution. Then, I add a reference of Class Library to MVC 5 project.

How do I use `Entity Framework` in class library and reference to MVC 5 and other projects if I have using same database.

Comment: Install Entity Framework with nuget in the class library. Because the class library is a dependency of the MVC application, and entity framework a dependency of the class library, EF will automatically become a dependency of the MVC application as well.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have the connection string in the client project, in your case MVC project. Either in a web.config or app.config. In your case, it's web.config file. Then you can safely generate your EntityFramework classes in your class library, and can refer to it from any type of project.